# no key defined EntityFramework CTP5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-ctp5

I'm running MVC3 with EntityFramework CTP5, SQL Server 2008

I don't believe this is the issue but figure I might mention it.
Because I'm lazy I created Linq to SQL and copied the property definitions and pasted into my own Model, then deleted the dbml file.

Is it possible that some of the data types might be wrong for the EntityFramework?
I'm still fairly new to EntityFramework.

I added the [key] annotation.

```
[Key]
public System.Guid FormID;
```

I still get this error.

```
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation: 
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'FormInfo' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: The EntitySet FormInfoes is based on type FormInfo that has no keys defined.
```

I noticed that "FormInfo" is set in the EntitySet to "FormInfoes". So, I added this to my context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

I initializing the context.

```
DbDatabase.SetInitializer<SQLServerContext>(null);
```

Since the DB is already there, I don't want to recreate or drop it.

Thanks for anyone's help!

Comment: I added this line of code to remove the "es" from "FormInfoes"

modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingEntitySetNameConvention>();

Still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a field. Not a property. Change the declaration to a property

```
[Key]
public System.Guid FormID { get; set; }
```

Comment: So that fixed most of the issues. But I'm now getting this:

Comment: System.Data.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'XElement' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

Comment: System.Data.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: The EntitySet XElement is based on type XElement that has no keys defined.

Comment: It would be difficult to map framework classes. You would need to use the fluent API to configure the key. `modelBuilder.Entity<XElement>().HasKey(x => x.Foo)`

Comment: Thanks Eranga for all your help.

Comment: I'm not sure if this was correct, but I simply mapped/converted the data type to string, this didn't give me any trouble. public string XMLData { get; set; } // XMLData in the db is XML Type